# PHP Stripe API: one time purchase plus subscription with 3D secure

Tags: php, stripe-payments, subscription

Hello and nice day to everyone!

We are currently building stripe integration (PHP), but are facing problems regarding the valid approach.

The case is, that our e-commerce has business model, where you are buying some physical good (usually one item per purchase) and the you pick type of support plan for that item (subscription with trial).

Practically, it shall go like:

you pay one-time purchase

you subscribe to support plan with certain trial (30 days)

after 30 days you got charged

So in the same time you pay for the product and sign for subscription with trial period.

It shall be 3D secure protected, so our customers wont be bothered with authentication when trial ends.

Sadly, we didnt figured it out yet :(

What kind of approach shall we use? Thanks for any answer and your time

Comment: There's no way to guarantee that future payments on a Subscription won't require 3DS authentication. Recurring payments generally receive an exception from the bank to not require 3DS on each payment, but the bank may decide to require auth for some future payments for whatever reason. So, your integration needs to be able to handle this. https://stripe.com/docs/billing/migration/strong-customer-authentication#sca-impact

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify a trial period(one month) when you set up the plan in stripe, then the money will be deducted automatically at that time.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually, the thing is that any next subscription payment has to be verified by 3D again...

Comment: If so, you have to email your customers and give them an URL to confirm each payment. 
I agree it's troublesome.